# In a Bash script, loop through lines in a file and modify them?

Tags: bash, loops, sed

I'm just learning Bash scripting, and I couldn't quite find an answer on here that worked for me, so here's what I'm trying to do...

I've got file list.txt with contents like this..

```
group: 43  [message]
group: 312  [message]
group: 501210  [message]
```

In a bash script, I'm trying to loop through the whole file and fix the formatting as such (delete the colon, leave only one space between 'group' and the number, and ultimately then remove everything after the number):

```
group 43
group 312
group 501210
```

It should then be saved to that same file, list.txt, overwriting the previous contents. However, I can't even figure out how to remove the ':'..

Here's my code...

```
for line in $(< list.txt);do
sed 's/:/""/';
done
```

It appears to load the first line and then is lost in an infinite loop. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you don't need the for loop. sed one liner could do the job:

```
sed -ir 's/(group):( [0-9]+).*/\1\2/' list.txt
```

or the awk one-liner:

```
awk -F': | ' '{print $1,$2}' list.txt > /tmp/t.tmp && mv /tmp/t.tmp /path/to/list.txt
```

Comment: @mklement thank you for the hint for Mac. I have 0 experience with Mac OS. also I guess OS X sed has no `-i` either, what is the corresponding option?

Comment: `-i` does exist on OS X - same meaning: edit the file in place (overwrite it with `sed`'s output) - however, there's a *crucial difference*: to make it work on OS X, use `-i ''` - the `''` means: don't create a copy of the *original* file; if you wanted to create a copy, say with extension `.bak`, use `-i '.bak'`.

Comment: @mklement that is to say, the empty string after `-i` is required. good to know. thx.

Comment: Exactly. To summarize: On `OS X`, in the `sed` command, use `-E` instead of `-r`, and `-i ''` (must be *separate* option with empty string as argument) instead of just `-i`.

Comment: The use of an empty string is advised against in the `BSD sed` man page: `It is not recommended to give a zero-length extension when in-place editing files, as you risk corruption or partial content in situations where disk space is exhausted, etc.`

Comment: Thank you for the help! When I ran the sed command, I get the following error: 'sed: -e expression #1, char 27: invalid reference \2 on 's' command's RHS'

Also, the awk command worked like a charm! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Since this is about learning bash scripting you could do:

```
while read group nr rest
do
  printf "%s %d\n" "${group%:}" "$nr"
done < file > newfile && mv newfile file
```

or if "group" does not vary in the input file:

```
while read group nr rest
do
  printf "group %d\n" "$nr"
done < file > newfile && mv newfile file
```

But this would typically be slower than using `sed`, `awk`, etc..